# Not able to read UDP packets on a server using Python

Tags: python, sockets, server, udp

I'm trying to stream a video from a webcam installed on a BeagleBoneBlack (linux device) to a server (Windows server). The BeagleBone is connected to the Internet using DHCP (dynamic IP) and basically sends UDP packet to a server. On the server side I implemented a simple python program using sockets that should easily read UDP packet coming from a specific IP or on a specific port. In wireshark I'm able to see the packets arriving on the server but the python program is not able to catch them. I tried to listen on different IP such as 'localhost' or specific IP but nothing seems to work.

Python program server side:

```
import socket

IP = '192.168.23.240' #IP of the BeagleBone on Wireshark 
IP = '109.164.170.155' #IP of the router in which the BeagleBone is attached
IP = '0.0.0.0' #localhost
IP = '' #localhost
IP = '192.168.0.21' #IP localhost server
IP = 'localhost' #localhost
PORT = 5454

if __name__ == "__main__":

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((IP,PORT))   

    f = open('file.mp4','wb')
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(4096)
    print 'Receiving from: ' +str(addr)

    for i in xrange(1000):
         f.write(data)
         data, addr = s.recvfrom(4096)
         print 'receiving from ' + str(addr) + ' ...'

    f.close()
    s.close()
```

In wireshark server side:

[image]

How is possible that I'm able to read the packets in wireshark but not using a simple python program? Someone know what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you run your program verbatim as you posted, it listens on localhost only, while your Wireshark screenshot suggests you're sending packets to "real" NIC with private IP address.
2. Are you sure your program does not work? When I fed it with netcat command like so:

   `cat myfile | nc -u 127.0.0.1 5454`

it worked:

```
receiving from ('127.0.0.1', 38182) ...
receiving from ('127.0.0.1', 38182) ...
receiving from ('127.0.0.1', 38182) ...
```

Note I was sending from localhost to localhost. This reinforces hypothesis you have a simple network config/port configuration problem, not the Python program not working.

Do `netstat -a` on Windows machine to see if your program really listens on indicated address.

If it does, maybe your local Windows firewall blocks the connection? Can you try turning it off for a moment?

Comment: Yes, the program as is listen to localhost but I also tried IP such as 127.0.0.1 or the IP of the Beaglebone: 192.168.23.240 which gave me an error "[Errno 10049] 'The requested address is not valid in its context'". There could be a firewall on UDP somewhere but I do not understand why wireshark is able to read them. Btw, I know that sending file using UDP is not the best but I was just testing the connection.